# Why Isn't this Clean URL Not Taking Effect?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, clean-urls

I have this code and I used a generator but it isn't working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^chrisbrighton\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://chrisbrighton.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^iPhone5s.php /reviews/iphone/5s [L,R=301]
```

I'd like my URL to go FROM:

```
http://chrisbrighton.co.uk/iPhone5s.php
```

TO:

```
http://chrisbrighton.co.uk/reviews/iphone/5s/
```

Why isn't this working? The page doesn't load.

P.S: I have looked at other questions but as I don't understand it I need to provide my own code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are rewriting in reverse order, try this?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^iPhone5s.php /reviews/iphone/5s [L,R=301]
```

Rewrite rule FROM TO, you've messed TO with FROM

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand! Could you rewrite the code needed? Sorry.

Comment: Thanks, this time it loaded the page but I'm getting a 404 Not Found.

Comment: Now add your line after above: RewriteRule ^reviews/iphone/5s$ /iPhone5s.php [L] dunno if that will make infinite loop tho.. not that familiar with htaccess

Comment: After my line? Sorry. I'm lost. Could you please add the full code needed? Once it's working I won't need anymore help!

Comment: Ah, I did get an infinite loop.